# Search and Replace URL in Drupal 9 MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, replace, drupal, drupal-9

I need to move a Drupal 9 website to a different server and a lot of links have the old contain the old server URL. Normally for Word Press I use this tool - https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB https://interconnectit.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

You upload that to the server and it runs a script to search for your string, and then replaces it with the new string. Unfortunately this tool does not work with Drupal.

I tried to do a regular search and replace in VS Code with -

Search //old.url.com
Replace with //new.url.com

It found all the //old.url.com but after I imported the database there are still some links that do not redirect to the new url, one of these is /user, which is the page to login, If I go to new.url.com/user it redirects to old.url.com/user

Is there a way to do a search and replace on the database to replace the old URL?

Answer (score 0):

It is curious because Drupal 9 is not storing static URL in database.

Do you mean that content to be replaced is into node fields content ?

You should not use wide textual search and replace into sql files because all serialized data could be broken.

Maybe a solution could be to use `hook_entity_presave` filter on node in order to search and replace old urls into content.

You can find reference about it here :

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/9.0.x